# Write.table to Onedrive R-Script via PowerBI

Tags: r, powerbi

I have added the following R script to my query in PowerBI to write a csv file every time the dataset is refreshed.

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
   write.table(dataset, file ="curl --max-time 7200 --connect-timeout 7200 --ntlm -user","Myonedriveusername:Myonedrivepassword", 
  "http://companyname.sharepoint.com/personal/username/Documents/data.csv", sep = ",", append = 
   TRUE, quote = FALSE,col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

The script is running without any errors, but no file is being created in the specified sharepoint folder. What am I doing wrong?